# Using Django REST Framework with sessions-based CSRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, csrf

I am using Django + Django REST Framework in an environment where I cannot use cookie-based CSRF tokens; therefore I must run with `CSRF_USE_SESSIONS = True`.

The DRF web UI, however, depends on this cookie for all interactions. It appears this is set by reading the `csrftoken` cookie and settings the `X-CSRFToken` header on the subsequent request, which is then consumed by `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware.process_view()` if the hidden field is not included in the request body. This is set in this code from `rest_framework.templates.rest_framework.base.html`:

```
<script>
  window.drf = {
    csrfHeaderName: "{{ csrf_header_name|default:'X-CSRFToken' }}",
    csrfCookieName: "{{ csrf_cookie_name|default:'csrftoken' }}"
  };
</script>
```

DRF forms that do not use `POST` do contain the CSRF token in the form body, so not having the cookie means the web interface does not have access to the CSRF token at all, causing all `PUT`, `PATCH`, and `DELETE` requests to fail with a 403 response.

I *believe* this is a bug in DRF, but it is possible this is intended behavior. Can someone explain how DRF is intended to be used with `CSRF_USE_SESSIONS = True`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed in https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/pull/6207 and released as part of DRF 3.9.2. More complete context can be read at https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/6206.